# Changing values in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I everybody, I'm new to python world and I'm trying to learn pandas and tensorflow.
At the moment I've a dataframe with positive and negative values that I want to manage to resize.
For example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler, StandardScaler

df = pd.read_excel ('/Users/dataset.xlsx')
print(df[:])

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
df_absolute = df.abs()
df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(df_absolute)

#df_mod = df_scaled.loc[(df<0)] = df_scaled*-1

df_normalized = pd.DataFrame(df_mod)
print(df_normalized[:])
```

I've an error on the line with # and such as 'numpy.ndarray'.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and add the error.

Answer (score 0):

In the

```
df = pd.read_excel ('/Users/dataset.xlsx')
```

there is widespace ' ' should remove it

```
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/dataset.xlsx')
```

Comment: Ty it was only a typing error when I created this post. Some comment about the true problem in the line marked with #?